# How to control figure numbering in Lyx

Tags: floats, numbering, lyx

I have a single figure in a Lyx document, and it is part of a paragraph which itself is part of a section. It is expected that Lyx will produce a caption for it as 'Figure 1: ....', however, the actual output I get is 'Figure 0.1: ...'. I don't think I explicitly ask Lyx to number the figures by section.

Any clue on why this happens and how I can fix it? In addition, is it possible to eliminate the numbering of captions (not the captions themselves) all together? Many thanks.

P.S. The document class I am using is 'handout (Tufte)' and the paragraph (which itself is of standard text) containing the figure is after two itemized paragraphs, if those make any difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some classes number figures and tables and perhaps further objects by chapter or by section. Let's say in your case it's section. Besides printing the section number before the figure number, the figure counter is reset to zero at the beginning of each section. The [`chngcntr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) package helps to change this. Here for example:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
```

Just put these lines in your LyX document preamble. You can add further such lines if necessary, to be consistent, such as

```
\counterwithout{table}{section}
```

if you use tables.

For suppressing numbering and further customization I recommend using the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package. For example:

```
\usepackage[figurewithin=none]{caption}
```

Its command `\caption*` works without numbering.

Comment: Insightful! Searched for a while on google but didn't find anything like this. thanks!