# Progressive Figure Numbering

Tags: numbering

I am writing a small paper for my school using LaTeX. 
In LaTex, the default figure numbering is done per-chapter ( 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, etc)

However, my school's guidelines specify that figure numbering should be done progressively.
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc)

I'm sure that there is a simple way to do this in LaTeX, but I have not been able to find any documentation about this yet.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28019/continuous-numbering-of-figures-and-tables?rq=1 help?

Comment: That was quick... Indeed, using that technique makes it work as intended. I was unable to find it before, however. Thank you