# Labeling figures as Figure 1, 2, 3 in LyX

Tags: floats, lyx

I am making a document in LyX but my figures are labelled here as figure 2.1, figure 3.1, figure 3.2 etc instead of figure 1, figure 2etc. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: More or less duplicate of [How to control figure numbering in Lyx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23929) I think. If the 2 in *figure 2.1* is the chapter number you need `chapter` in `counterwithout` of course.

Comment: i corrected that by making changes in Dcument-> settings-> modules -> deleting "figure name by sections"   It worked!

Answer (score 2):

As you discover ...

<kbd>Document</kbd> > <kbd>Settings...</kbd> > <kbd>Modules</kbd> > <kbd>Number Figures by Section</kbd> > <kbd>Delete</kbd>

[image: mwe]

This remove `\numberwithin{figure}{section}` in the LaTeX Preamble (as well as `\usepackage{amsmath}` if not needed by another command).

Note that in LaTeX preamble you can use also the `chngcntr` package to control the numeration of floats. See  [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume) for more information.